# How to upload via REST API

Tags: json, angular, rest, primeng

I have an angular 5 app and I'm using the primeng upload tool. the api post for uploading requires three parameters: file (file), id (string), fileType (string). I can do the latter two but the file type i just don't understand. the latter two are strings, got it, but how do i address the file part?

this is my json post:

```
[{ "file" : <<DATA>>, "id": "1234123", "fileType": "doc" }]
```

What and how to I put in something for the file type?

Comment: filetype is usually the file extensions and the data is the file serialised to a string

Answer (score 1):

PrimeNG FileUpload's documentation is quite good so I'd suggest taking a closer look at the documentation at: [PrimeNG File Upload](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload)

For your specific requirement, I'd suggest taking PrimeNG File Upload and make it as "fancy file picker". Snippets as below:

```
HTML
<p-fileUpload 
  name="demo[]" 
  auto="true"
  customUpload="true" 
  (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)" 
  multiple="multiple">
</p-fileUpload>

TS
myUploader(event) {
 consol.log(event.files) //This will return all of the files that are selected. You can omit multiple files by getting rid of `multiple` attribute from the template
//Take this event.files and do whatever you want with it
}
```

[Plunker example, turn on the Console](https://plnkr.co/edit/eqLZnv?p=preview)
[image: File object in console]

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. what about the json? how does that look?

Comment: @azmatrix take a look at the Plunker example I provided. You can turn on the Console then try choosing a file. I edited my answer

Comment: okay thanks. what about the data of the file? i only attributes of the file, what about the data?